# Need a way to extract the url out of hyperlinks

Tags: c#

i want to copy paste hyperlinks in a input field optimally and get out the url of this hyperlink have not found a solution till now on google or anywhere else

Comment: You're most likely searching to specifically.  I would suggest searching for parsing html... something like [Html Agility Pack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) would get you started.

Comment: If you want to get the answer you should describe the problem properly. You haven't said whether you refer to UWP or desktop .NET or possibly something else like .NET Core. It is extremely confusing what "get out the url of this hyperlink" means for you as URL is reachable from hyperlink.

Comment: sry didnt make that clear its in visual studio so yeah .NET and i simply want the url from this hyperlink i give into an input field in an string sry again im still pretty new to programming